# Bcrypt is not supported in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, bcrypt

I try to convert the form input password value using bcrypt.
First I installed bcrypt (npm install bcrypt --save) after I added like this

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
 var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(values.newPassword, 10);
```

Then in the cmd display so mush errors like this

```
 ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in
```

What's the cause of the error, and how can the problem be resolved?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So the normal bcrypt isn't like a typical library. It's written in c++ and compiled for your machine when you `npm install` it. It does not work in the browser because of that (and more). However, there is a pure javascript implementation that IS browser compatible (and portable in general):

[bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs)

```
npm install bcryptjs
```

Do read their browser implementation to guide through setup. They have a few small things needing to be done to generate the cryptographically safe random numbers.

Answer (score -1):

var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

Comment: please avoid code only answers, instead you want to format your code and give an explanation

Comment: what makes you think they're not actually using https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt? And what on earth does this add on top of the existing answer? Did you mean to suggest an edit to that answer?