# How can I use Crypto built-in module from Node.JS in React Native Project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, bcrypt

I'm working on a `React Native project` and I need to implement authentication, with an encrypted password.

I want to use `library Bcrypt` but I have an issue. `Bcrypt` requires the `Crypto module`, which was a third-part library, but now it is a built-in module in `Node.js`.

When I try to use Bcrypt with `const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')`, it throws an error :

> Unable to resolve module 'crypto' from 'node_modules/bcrypt/...'

I am using :

- Node.js v13.0.1
- NPM v6.12.0
- react-native-cli v2.0.1
- react-native v0.61.3
- react v16.9.0

To manage this error, I went to `Node.js` documentation and tried the solution to know if the `Crypto` built-in module is available or not but it throws the same error.

Maybe I don't understand clearly what is a built-in module, **is that a module which is included into the Node.js installer**, so I don't have any NPM install crypto to do?

If it is the case, does anyone have an idea about **why I can't use it in my project**?

I also tried the `rn-nodeify module`, with `react-native-bcrypt` and `react-native-crypto`, but in each case some packages weren't reached, like `stream`, `VM`, `fs`, etc.

**Do you encountered the same problem and solved it?**

Comment: Why do you want to crypt the password in your mobile app? it should be done I think in your back-end code it will be more helpful and reduce authentication process time

Comment: Well, the way I will use it is not defined precisely. What I would like to do is encrypt the password that is submitted and then compare with the one in my database, only if the username is in the database.
What you recommend is to encrypt the password during the fetch post method ?
I am new to React Native, but if I am not wrong, in my project, my back-end is composed by web services / web API which search the results or post the requests when I use a fetch method in my front end component. 
Is that rude to use fetch method in the front-end ?

Comment: Do you use nodejs express for your back-end ?

Comment: No, express is not used in this project. Do you think it might be the problem ?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out why it is not working. I am not in a node project but I am in a RN project, so packages are not the same. What an idiot I am !

Answer (score 1):

Someone already answered that question here
[Bcrypt is not supported in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49443296/bcrypt-is-not-supported-in-reactjs)
It's because bcrypt is written in C++.
But now they have bcryptjs, the JS version of bcrypt. You can download it here https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs.
Note that bcryptjs is slower than the C++ version - bcrypt, because "it is written in pure JavaScript and thus slower (about 30%), effectively reducing the number of iterations that can be processed in an equal time span."

Answer (score 0):

I would request you to look into [rn-nodeify](https://github.com/tradle/rn-nodeify#rn-nodeify) library. It enables you to use core modules and npm modules in your react-native app.

Look into this answer [rn-nodeify installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53778566/7684651) and start from **Step 2**.

I hope i could help you.

Comment: I already tried with this package following the tutorial installation provided here [rn-nodeify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-nodeify) and the results weren't great. But I'll try the link you sent me, in the case of. I'll make you a return. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/margelo/react-native-quick-crypto
I've used this lib
the fix for endian.h is to rename it to <machine/endian.h>