# How to use bcryptjs with ES6 NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, bcrypt

I'm trying to use `bcryptjs` package in my React project. I'm getting following error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'bcryptjs'. ‘…/node_modules/bcryptjs/index.js' 
implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/bcryptjs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts)
file containing `declare module 'bcryptjs';`
```

Running `npm i --save-dev @types/bcryptjs` makes import error to go away but when I try to use variables from the package, they are not found.

NodeJS version is node `v16.17.0` and TS is use as well.

How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: maybe this helps you?:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49443296/bcrypt-is-not-supported-in-reactjs

Answer (score 3):

Try using below option:

```
npm i bcryptjs @types/bcryptjs
```

and then, add the below line

```
import { hash, compare } from 'bcryptjs';
```

Make sure that `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports"` is set to `"true"` in your `tsconfig.json` file

Answer (score 1):

Try running the command `npm i --save-dev @types/bcryptjs`
or `yarn add --dev @types/bcryptjs` if you're using yarn to get the type definitions for this module.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
To fix it, I first did:

```
yarn add bcryptjs @types/bcryptjs
```

And then removed the curly braces, when importing bcrypt. So, instead of:

```
import { bcrypt } from 'bcryptjs';
```

I did:

```
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
```

Answer (score 0):

Running

> npm i --save-dev @types/bcryptjs

makes import error to go away..

#RUN IN ROOT FOLDER FIRST